# Run Angular directly from dist by double clicking index.html

Tags: angular

Up to Angular 13 I was able to run the project by double clicking index.html from the dist folder. The only requirement was to add
`*<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');  </script>*`
to `index.html`.

This doesn’t seem to be enough in Angular 15 anymore, I get CORS errors, for example:

> index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/work/Angular/angV15/dist/ang-v15/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which operation system do you have and which tool youre using? A Javascript file cannot be executed by double click without a HTTP server.

Comment: I don't think the OS matters, it's web technology and runs in the browser. Tools => Angular Cli. I'm not trying to run JavaScript code by double clicking on it, I'm opening a html file.